# C++ Error with returning object of the same type as the return paramater

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an assignment in which we are tasked with developing a class that mimics the same behavior as the string class in the standard library. Our string class exists in a separate namespace and is not using any part of the standard library. The class is defined in a header file and implemented in a cpp file. The issue I have is with overloading the + operator and returning a new string object that holds the concatenated string. Code here:

```
String String::operator+(String & str) const {

    char *returnString = new char[str._size + this->_size - 1] 
    // both null terminated strings and this gets the correct size of the new string

    // code concatenating string and storing it in a char * returnString
    // user recommend i remove this since it is not apart of my question


    return String(returnString);
}
```

I am getting an error on the return statement that reads as follows:

> Returning 'String' from a function returning 'String': Class 'String' is not compatible with class 'String'

I also tried to declare a string variable and return it, something like:

```
String s1(returnString);
return s1;
```

This doesn't give an error and lets me to compile but this does not work since the variable falls out of scope and the destructor is called. I have also attempted removing the const from the function declaration to still no avail.

EDIT: the header file was given to us by the professor and we cannot change the function return type, name, or number of arguments. So I cannot change the return type.

EDIT 2: The string class is defined in the same namespace as the actual definitions of the functions. Essentially, the string class needs to be able be initialized by a string literal and needs to be able to be dynamically altered if it is added to. This plus operator is just meant to take another string object, combine the data and return a new object that contains the new string that is made up of the data from both of the original objects

Comment: "this does not work since the variable falls out of scope and the destructor is called." No it does not. The variable is moved or copied out to the destination first. You cannot return a *reference* to a local variable, a value of it is fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should not remove the const marker. It helps make sure that you don't change `this`. In fact, you should probably add `const` before `String & str`. Unfortunately, I don't know what's going on with that error, except that I'm tempted to say, "Welcome to C++." :-)

Comment: Can you tell us more about the `String` class?

Comment: What compiler are you using? is a copy constructor defined and implemented?

Comment: Also, is a move constructor defined and implemented? Does the destructor delete the `char *` data?

Comment: @JohnPerry I added a small edit trying to explain the string class more thoroughly. I am using MinGW and developing it in the CLion IDE.

Comment: @JohnPerry there is a copy constructor that works and I have tested it. The destructor does delete the char * data as well yes

Comment: @DavidArico One problem with the second approach is in the destructor, then, because it deletes the `char *` data. Can you give the full error data on the `return String(returnString)` statement?

Comment: You hide important things from us. Paste [mcve].

Comment: @JohnPerry the additional error message: 
'In member function 'CS52::String CS52::String::operator+(char*) const'
'error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'CS52::String&' to an rvalue of type 'CS52::String'

Comment: Right, the error message is telling us a lot more. You need to add the full error message to your post. (In fact, that's very different from what's in your post.)

Comment: ...well, except the error doesn't make sense. It says the error is coming from `String::operator+(char*) const` but your post has `String::operator+(String &) const`. Are you giving the right error here?

Comment: @JohnPerry im sorry, i have two functions that do that just take different parameters, the one with the char * does the same thing as the one that takes the String object argument except is makes a string object with that char * first. I pasted the wrong error message, im sorry.
In member function 'CS52::String CS52::String::operator+(CS52::String&) const':
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'CS52::String&' to an rvalue of type 'CS52::String'
         return String(returnString);

Comment: What is the signature of the copy constructors?

Comment: @DanielH The three constructors i have are:

`String()`

`String(char *str)`

`String(String& string)`

The variable `returnString` is a `char *` so wouldnt it call the second constructor?

Comment: @DavidArico Yep, and then you have a `String` rvalue (approximately, something that's the result of an expression instead of being a named variable). You need to copy that to return it, and since your copy constructor accepts a `String&` instead of a `String const&`, you can't. This would be different in C++17, which changes the rules around temporaries, but your post is tagged C++11 instead.

Comment: @DavidArico Sorry, I had to step away a while. Daniel H has outlined the solution for you, though: you need to add `const` to the parameter type for the copy constructors.